# MySQL Error 1005: can't create table. Regarding using foreign keys as multi-column primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a many-to-many table `user_processes` that consists of two columns: `user` and `process`. `user` is a foreign key referencing the user table's primary key. The `process` column is a foreign key referencing the processes primary key. However, I don't need a separate primary key column in `user_processes` since a multi-column primary key on `user`, `process` should be enough (right? I'm not seeing a need for a separate `id` column). One user can have many processes, but there shouldn't be multiple rows with the same user having the same process.

The following code is giving me the error "#1005 - Can't create table 'test.user_processes' (errno: 150) (Details...) " in phpmyadmin.

Here's the code, generated by mysql workbench:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`user_processes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`user_processes` (
  `user` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `process` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`, `process`) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_processes_users1_idx` (`user` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_processes_processes1_idx` (`process` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_processes_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_processes_processes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`process` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`processes` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Any idea why it's not letting me do this, and what the right solution is?

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the two referenced tables as well. Usually the 150 error is due to a mismatch of data types between the parent and child tables, or a missing index on the parent table.

Comment: For example, if either `users.id` or `processes.id` is not `UNSIGNED` or a different `INT` length, you would get this error.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. Like I told Arnold, you'd think that MySQL Workbench would notify me of these problems before forward engineering them. Isn't that what the program is supposed to accomplish, to help with data integrity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `users` and/or `processes` might not exists. Make sure that the create table statements for the referenced tables are executed before calling this.

Or the type of the referenced fields `users.id` and/or `processes.id` don't match the type of the fields `user_processes.user` / `user_processes.process`. In this case, those fields should also be `INT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out the field type didn't match (used mediumint instead of int). I probably spent an additional 10-20 minutes going through the rest of the errors that popped up, such as missing quotes around ENUM defaults, and others. You'd think that MySQL Workbench would notify me of these problems before forward engineering them...